# How to escape ^ character in GET Request using Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am sending a `GET` Request which contains special character like `^`. I am using Tomcat 7. Somehow tomcat is unable to escape `^` character and fails to handle the request. I have added `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in `server.xml` file and `tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=^` in `catalina.properties` but its not working.

Comment: try encoding ^ as %5E https://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters/

Comment: I know it's not a good solution, but if you really in a rush, maybe you encode "^" to something like "---" and decode that charcter in the receviver file :)

Comment: [Section 2.4.3 of the URI specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-2.4.3) clearly states that `^` is not a valid character in a URI.  As canillas said, you need to escape it as `%5e` in the URI.